# Spectate league of legends game and retrive data

Tags: web-scraping, web-crawler, data-retrieval, riot-games-api, spectator

I want to code a script to **retrieve data from league of legends game while spectating**. I want to open the league of legends client, join a game as a spectator, then run the script, and the script collects all the game data, champ damage, gold etc and **save that to a json** file.**then display that data nicely on a webpage** and the gold and players damage as graphs.

Does riot games apis provide such a thing or if there's anything on GitHub I can use for this kinda job?

Answer (score 1):

I didn't tried this, but I think [LCU API](https://riot-api-libraries.readthedocs.io/en/latest/lcu.html) can help you.
You can may open League of Legend client and join as a spectator with this.

But unfortunately, there is no official LCU API documentation, so you can see [this documentation](https://www.hextechdocs.dev/lol/lcuapi/6.getting-started-with-the-lcu-api).

I hope I can help you.

Answer (score 0):

There's an [API for downloading the match timeline](https://developer.riotgames.com/apis#match-v5/GET_getTimeline) which is probably what you're after. There's no need to spectate a game to get it, you just need to register for an API key, and then you can download it using the match ID.

Answer (score -1):

The way I was able to get around it is by using ocr to read the screen, I can grab anything that is displayed, but for damage currently there is no way. If you want a gold graph its best to make it yourself in python.